# No change after installing Icon theme

Tags: icon-themes

I was trying MOKA- icon theme.Installed it from Ubuntu Software Center.Restarted the system but no change in Icon so far.Where am I wrong!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The icon theme won't change unless you make it the default icon set. Use unity tweak tool to change the icon theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.I've just discovered that you can change Icon theme from Unity Tweak Tool.